# How to install the packages needed for a Python Script to execute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-import, python-module

I have created a python script which has certain modules to be imported. I used PyCharm and imported them.However, from a normal script perspective, when I run it using command line 'python file.py',it throws error no module found. So how do you import the required modules through command line, if possible through a single command?

***The Modules I need:***

```
import time
import psutil
import win32api
from win32con import MB_SYSTEMMODAL
```

Kindly help me with this

Comment: Have you installed those module in your machine? if no, you can install them by running command ```pip install modulname``` and if you want to run import from the command line you need to specify the modules that you want, using -m for example ```python -m module yourfile.py```.

Comment: I haven't installed them, pip install modulename is fine, but do I have to do this individually for each module before running the script. Say I'm using giving this script to a user, and should I ask him to do it individually? I wan't a more user friendly solution

Comment: you can create setup.py for your project, then the user only need to run ```pip install setup.py``` it'll install your app with the requirements but you need to make setup.py on your own [read here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), or you can save the requirement using ```pip freeze > requirements.txt``` then your client only need to run ```pip install -r requirements.txt``` or you can use pipenv for more simple.

Comment: I already used pip freeze > requirements.txt, thank you